# What does -f mean in bash

Tags: bash, operators

I was looking at how to use [runit to run gunicorn](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html#runit). I was looking at the bash file and I don't know what `-f $PID` does in

```
#!/bin/sh

GUNICORN=/usr/local/bin/gunicorn
ROOT=/path/to/project
PID=/var/run/gunicorn.pid

APP=main:application

if [ -f $PID ]; then rm $PID; fi

cd $ROOT
exec $GUNICORN -c $ROOT/gunicorn.conf.py --pid=$PID $APP
```

Google is useless in this case because searching for flags is useless

Comment: i think `-f` checks for file or not.

Comment: pick the one from the below answers. :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj When I wrote that there were no answers and I have to wait 10 min before I can accept.

Comment: Although the question is tagged as bash, and you call the script a "bash file", you are using `sh` in the hash-bang line, not `bash`.  In this case the behaviour is no different, but you cannot always count on that.  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: Googling for [bash "-f"](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+%22-f%22) works fine. The quotes are significant, though.

Comment: @tipleee: except the code in the question does not use bash (OK, sh might be a symbolic link to bash, but we don't know that)

Comment: when searching for  exact programming expressions I find https://duckduckgo.com/ usually works better than https://www.google.com/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Google is useless in this case because searching for flags is useless

Fortunately, the *Bash Reference Manual* is available online, at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html. It's the first hit when you Google for "Bash manual". [§6.4 "Bash Conditional Expressions"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) says:

> `-f file`
>
> > True if *file* exists and is a regular file.

Answer (score 8):

> -f - file is a regular file (not a directory or device file)

Check this out for all file test operators:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html

Comment: What if I see something like `Exec="/opt/CLion/bin/clion.sh" %f`. What the `%f` stands for?

Answer (score 6):

The `[` is the same as the command `test` which allows you to test certain things. Try `help test` to find out what the flags are. Things to be careful with are spaces - the `[` needs a space after it.

Comment: FWIW this is the only answer that attempts to explain the situation rather than just " `-f` test if a file exists"

Answer (score 1):

`-f` checks if the file exists and is a regular file.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ -f "$var" ]
```

Checks if `$var` is an existing file (regular file). Symbolic link passes this test too.