# What means "[ -f ./path/to/file.xml ]"?

Tags: bash, terminal

what does the following terminal expression mean?

```
[ -f ./path/to/file.xml ]
```

Thank you!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453502/what-does-f-mean-in-an-if-statement-in-a-bash-script

Comment: Thank you! Couldn't find it on my own.

Comment: Just googled "bash minus f" to get the link for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does -f mean in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825762/what-does-f-mean-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

It means if there exist file.xml at location `./path/to/file.xml` .